# Background Image for all pages in HTML

Tags: html, css, jsp, background-image

Is there any way to insert default background image into HTML for all pages. I want same background for all page. Adding background to page one by one is hard for me because I have 35 pages. I am using JSP.

Comment: Look up templates in JSP

Comment: You could use an application-scoped variable. That way you could use something like ${backgroundImage} .  You could set the variable in a Servlet that is loaded on start-up of your web app.

Comment: You could use a JSP include. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnajb.html

Answer (score 4):

```
body {
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
}
```

Comment: It is a solution for one page. I want solution for all pages. For example by using web.xml is there any solution?

Comment: @GürkanÇatak So call your css to all pages